# How to activate an installed network driver

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet, realtek

The ethernet connection suddenly stopped working after a restart happened.
`lshw -c network` yields `*-network UNCLAIMED`. From what I've read in various forums, it would seem
that no network driver is active. I searched the product `RTL8111/8168/8411` and found that I needed the realtek `r8168` driver. I downloaded and run the `.deb` file and everything seemed to be installed correctly. However after a restart and and a `service network-manager restart` nothing seems to be working. I ran `lsmod` but could not find the name of the driver I installed in the output.

Any thoughts? Please forgive my inexperience, I will provide more info upon request.
I have kubuntu 20.04

EDIT:
`sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r816` outputs:
`modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-36-generic`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r816` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you for your comment, i updated the question, it seems it is not found anywhere in the system

Comment: How about: `sudo modprobe r8168 && dmesg | greo r816`?

Comment: @chili555 Same output as before :(

Comment: If you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu, does the ethernet work again? Also, please show us: `sudo dkms status` and: `sudo dpkg -s r8168-dkms | grep Status`

Comment: @chili555 I installed kubuntu as dual-boot along windows. I was never able to install grub. The way i choose between the two operating systems is by hitting f11 at startup time and choosing a partition. I don't know how to boot into an earlier kernel version. Could you be aa little more specific

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118470/discussion-between-chili555-and-vlassisfo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our chat, we determined that a recent update installed a 5.8.0-36 kernel version and that, for unknown reasons, the package *linux-modules-extra* that provides the relevant ethernet driver r8169 was not installed.

You were able to successfully get to the boot menu and GRUB. You selected an earlier kernel version, 5.4.0-60. Then I suggested the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic
sudo apt purge r8168-dkms
```

Upon reboot back into your 5.8.0-36 kernel version, the ethernet was now working as expected.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad it's working! It was a pleasure working with you on this interesting case.

Comment: I has the same problem, except that my attempts tofix it seems to have broken kernel 5.4.0-60. Luckily manually downloading (using another computer) and installing linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Also after upgrading kernel to 5.8.0-38 the corresponding linux-modules-extra package was again missing. It seem Canonical wants to be more like Microsoft when it comes to system updates...

Comment: And the same thing happened again after upgrade to 5.8.0-40... Why, Canonical, why?

Comment: I investigated the issue further and it seem that the package `linux-generic`, which pulls all the other kernel-related packages as dependencies, is no longer updated and if one wants the `linux-modules-extra` to stay updated, one needs to install `Linux-generic-hwe-20.04`. I whish they warned us about that.

Comment: I struggled with this problem two evenings, but thanks to this answer it is solved now. Thanks a lot.